# Mouse wheel scrolling doesn't work in Pane inside ExpressionCell

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, cells

Essentially what the title says - Consider the following example:

```
ExpressionCell[Pane[
  200!,
  ImageSize -> {200, 200},
  Scrollbars -> {False, Automatic}
  ]]
```

[image]

When trying to scroll around in the pane using the mouse wheel, the whole notebook is scrolled through instead. Manually grabbing the scrollbar with the cursor to scroll still works. Also, removing the `ExpressionCell` returns the behavior to normal.

Is there any option or similar that I am missing? Scrolling using the scrollbar is rather cumbersome… Unfortunately, I need the `ExpressionCell` to be there, so I am in need for another workaround.

Comment: If you absolutely need it in an inline cell, then no.  That should only happen with this example thanks to the Shift+Enter evaluation.  If you try your example with an " // CellPrint" appended to the end, it should behave as desired.

Comment: @ihojnicki no inline cell scrolling? What’s behind that restriction?

Comment: @ihojnicki thanks for the definitive answer once again. Unfortunately, I think I do need the inline cell, but I guess I'll have to recheck for alternatives... (I am using the inline cell as storage for `TaggingRules` in order to have front-end state variables that can be dynamically created. As far as I am aware, this is not doable with `DynamicModule` variables, since the front-end can't reliably interact with list variables, right? Using an inline cell instead of the output cell itself allows easy copying of the whole thing and enables multiple such expressions in a single output cell)

Comment: @b3m2a1, you can scroll it using the mouse wheel once the inline cell has been activated.  I haven't gone digging through the code to see why that is the case, but it could simply be a bug.

Comment: @LukasLang, list variables?  I think I would need to see a small example to comment further.

Comment: @ihojnicki What do you mean by "once the cell has been activated"? (I tried clicking into the pane to focus it before scrolling, but it didn't make a difference).

Comment: @ihojnicki Regarding the list variables: Sorry, I wasn't very clear - here is an example: `NotebookOpen[CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/2656d4a5-89fc-4ee7-8d91-e51343dd8d35"]]`. Clicking the button adds new items to the list, each with its own state variable (click on them to toggle them) that is completely handled by the FE (kernel is only involved for the initial creation). I am not aware of a way to do this using normal `DynamicModule` variables, since there doesn't seem to be a way for the FE to do e.g. `vars[[1]] = 2` on its own.

Comment: @LukasLang, yeah.  The FE's evaluator does not have feature parity with the kernel (this is by design).  What you are asking it to do is something it is uncomfortable with.  As for activation, clicking on the contents of pane should change the background color to a tan'ish color.  The scrollwheel should then operate as expected.

Comment: @ihojnicki Regarding the scrolling: For me, the scroll wheel unfortunately does not work even if the background is brownish - I've tested it on 11.3 for MacOS, 11.3 for Windows and 12.0 for Windows.